# Two lines passing through $(-2,5)$ making angles $\arctan\frac 34$ & $\arctan\frac 23$ with the line $x-y+5=0$.Find the equations of the lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems

Two straight lines pass through the point $(-2,5)$ such that one of them makes an angle of $\arctan \frac 34$

with the given line $x-y+5=0$

and the given line makes an angle of $\arctan \frac 23$

with the other line . Find the equations of the two lines.
$\bf{Try} :$
Let the equation of the line be $y=mx+c$.$\cdots (1)$
If $(1)$ makes angle $\theta$ with the given line then $\tan\theta =| \frac {m-1}{1+m}|$
So by the given condition we have

$| \frac {m-1}{1+m}|=\frac 34$
Solving we get $m=7,\frac 17$
Putting these values of $m$ and using the condition that the line passes through $(-2,5)$ we get two lines as
$y=7x+19  \cdots (2)$
$7y=x+37\cdots (3)$
Similarly $| \frac {m-1}{1+m}|=\frac 23$
gives $m=5,\frac 15$ and we get the equations of the lines as
$y=5x+15\cdots (4)$
and $5y=x+27\cdots (5)$
But the answer is given as the lines $(2)$ and $(5)$. Why the lines $(3)$ and $(4)$ are excluded?

Comment: You are correct; the book is wrong.

Comment: the book is treating $\arctan(\frac{3}{4})$ as a positive angle with respect to the given line and hence considering $m \gt 1$ for line $1$. In the second case, the given line is making a positive angle of $\arctan {\frac{2}{3}}$ to line $2$ and hence it is taking the slope for line $2$ to be $\lt 1$.

Comment: Nonetheless, the problem is poorly-worded:  "makes an angle with" is generally understood to refer to the _included_ angle between the lines, without an implied direction to the angle.  (The arctangent values simply imply that the two angles are less than 45º.)   Also, there are any number of "gotcha" versions of such problems in which you would be in error to _omit_ the other possibility.  Without better clarification, both pairs of lines would be acceptable as answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In coordinate geometry angles are usually measured in counter-clockwise direction from positive $x-$ axis. Your book is probably following that convention. You need to find two lines $L_1$ and $L_2$, where $L_1$ is the line that makes angle of $\arctan \frac34$ with the given line.

The given line makes an angle of $\frac \pi 4$ with positive $x-$ axis. So the angle that $L_1$ makes with positive $x-$ axis $=\frac \pi 4+\arctan \frac 34$ and so slope (gradient) of $L_1=\tan (\pi/4+\arctan \frac 34)=7$ and since this line passes through $(-2,5)$, its equation is: $y-5=7(x+2)$ 
Similarly, you may get equation of $L_2$.

Comment: So for the other line gradient will be $tan(\frac {\pi}4 - \arctan(\frac 23))=\frac 15$. But my question is If I don't have calculator then how to decide which line is above the given line and which is below (geometrically) i.e when to add the angle and when to subtract?

Comment: As per the convention (that is measuring angles counter-clockwise), the gradient for the other line is $\tan (\pi/4 +\arctan\frac 23)$. Probably your books is finding line that lie on opposite sides of the given line. To decide orientation use the fact that $\tan $ is an increasing function.

Comment: Now forgetting what book means to say, we can consider all four cases taking the $\pm$ signs in consideration?

Comment: @Math-Learner:That’s correct.

Answer (score -2):

{Red (2) Orange (3) Violet (4) Grey(5)} all for image if I will be able to upload image.

If question strictly wants positive angle for  statement then:

(3) makes $-\tan^{-1}(\frac {3}{4})$ with $x-y+5=0$

Similarly (4) makes $-\tan^{-1}(\frac{2}{3})$ with $x-y+5=0$

You may draw graph to check.[image]

Comment: $-\tan^{-1}\frac 34$ is not positive angle.

Comment: Yes so (3) is excluded.

Comment: What wrong I said?